# Chart.js the value on the graph does not disappear when deselected

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I have a line chart where the values are visible (I have used the code found in other posts on the site).

But if I unselect an argument, only the line disappears but not its value. Can you help me? This is a very good library.

Here is my code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var nomi = [2017,2018,2019];

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: nomi,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'PP PERVENUTI',
            data: [50,30,45],
            backgroundColor: "#8A0808",
   fill: false,
            borderColor: "#8A0808",
            borderWidth: 3
        },
  {
            label: 'PP EVASI',
            data: [60,45,12],
            backgroundColor: "#0B610B",
   fill: false,
            borderColor: "#0B610B",
            borderWidth: 3
        },
  {
            label: 'PI PERVENUTI',
            data: [20,25,35],
            backgroundColor: "#8A0886",
   fill: false,
            borderColor: "#8A0886",
            borderWidth: 3
        },
  {
            label: 'PI EVASI',
            data: [10,20,30],
            backgroundColor: "#0404B4",
   fill: false,
            borderColor: "#0404B4",
            borderWidth: 3
        }  
  ]
    },
    options: {
  legend: {
   display : true,
   position : "bottom"
  },
  hover: {
   animationDuration: 0
  },
  animation: {
  onComplete: function () {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                for(var key in dataset._meta)
                {
     var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
  
    }
});
```

This is the result:

Not unselected

[image]

Unselected

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because the `animation.oncomplete` event is called again when the legend is filtered.

You need to have an extra check like this `dataset._meta[0].$filler.visible != false` to only show values for only visible datasets.

Below is corrected code or fiddle for your reference -> https://jsfiddle.net/x164L2z9/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var nomi = [2017, 2018, 2019];

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: nomi,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'PP PERVENUTI',
        data: [50, 30, 45],
        backgroundColor: "#8A0808",
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#8A0808",
        borderWidth: 3
      },
      {
        label: 'PP EVASI',
        data: [60, 45, 12],
        backgroundColor: "#0B610B",
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#0B610B",
        borderWidth: 3
      },
      {
        label: 'PI PERVENUTI',
        data: [20, 25, 35],
        backgroundColor: "#8A0886",
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#8A0886",
        borderWidth: 3
      },
      {
        label: 'PI EVASI',
        data: [10, 20, 30],
        backgroundColor: "#0404B4",
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#0404B4",
        borderWidth: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom"
    },
    hover: {
      animationDuration: 0
    },
    animation: {
      onComplete: function() {

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
          if (dataset._meta[0].$filler.visible != false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
              for (var key in dataset._meta) {
                var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
              }
            }
          }

        });
      }
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: Forgive me, Kunal Khivensara. It works perfectly in a graphic line. But I have the same problem in a graphic bar. The different code is: [code] this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i)
    {
     var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
     meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
      var data = dataset.data[index];                            
      ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
     });
    });  [/code]